# Change SVG text filled with video for SVG element filled with video

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

I've been able to show a video with a text mask, so the video is only showing inside the text. Now, I would like to do the same thing, but instead of using a normal text as a mask, I'd like to use a SVG element as the mask.

```css
.wrapper-video {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.wrapper-video-border {
 width: 102%;
 height: 102%;
 position: absolute;
 top: -1%;
 left: -1%;
 border: 10px solid #fff;
}

.project-initial {
 position:relative;
 margin-right: 0;
 font-size: 500px;
 letter-spacing: -10px;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 width: 720px;
 height: 405px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.project-initial .mask__shape {
 fill: white;
}

.project-initial .shape--fill {
 fill: #fff;
}

.project-initial .text--transparent {
 fill: transparent;
}

.project-initial .box-with-text {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.project-initial .text-fill {
 position: absolute;
 width: 720px;
 height: 405px;
 margin: auto;
}

.project-initial .video {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.project-initial .svg-defs {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
}

.project-initial .svg-inverted-mask {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-video">
  <div class="project-initial">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 720 405" class="svg-defs">
      <!-- Symbol with text -->
      <symbol id="s-text">
        <text text-anchor="middle"
              x="50%"
              y="50%"
              dy=".35em"
              class="text"
              >
          13
        </text>    
      </symbol>
      <!-- Mask with text -->
      <mask id="m-text"
            maskunits="userSpaceOnUse"
            maskcontentunits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              class="mask__shape">
        </rect>
        <use xlink:href="#s-text"
             class="mask__text"
             ></use>
      </mask>
    </svg>
    <div class="box-with-text">
      <!-- Container for video -->
      <div class="text-fill">
        <video  viewBox="0 0 720 405" 
               class="video" src="http://tympanus.net/codrops-playground/assets/images/posts/23145/bokeh2.mp4"
               autoplay loop
               ></video>
      </div>
      <!-- Visible SVG -->
      <svg viewBox="0 0 720 405"
           class="svg-inverted-mask">
        <rect
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              mask="url(#m-text)"
              class="shape--fill"/>
        <use xlink:href="#s-text"
             class="text--transparent"
             ></use>
      </svg> 
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-video-border"></div>
</div>
```

You can see it working in the JsFiddle above. Now, how could I edit this code to make it work with an SVG element instead of normal text?

Thank you!

Comment: Swap the text element for whatever other element you want. I don't really see the problem here.

Comment: If I change my text for an SVG, everything is blank as you can see here : https://jsfiddle.net/cd8pjvyb/

Comment: SVG can't be a child of a <text> element. If you remove the <text> element altogether it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you @RobertLongson, that was the problem.